# How to deploy Java and React based Web application on Azure Web app

Tags: java, reactjs, azure-web-app-service

I have web application with Java as backend and ReactJS as frontend. We want to deploy the application on Azure Web app service. In this context I have following ques

1. Is this best practice that we deploy both Backend and frontend in separate web app
2. Or can we deploy single web app containing both Backend and Frontend.

Please suggest which is best practice and pros and cons

Thank You

trying to understand best practice and pros and cons for above said problem

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the best option for opnion-based (pros/cons) questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252873.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

If your application is small and simple, it can be a good option to deploy backend and frontend in one web application. However, if your application is large and complex, it is recommended to implement the back-end and front-end in separate web applications for better scalability and security.

Nonetheless, this decision depends on many factors, including the complexity of the application, scalability requirements, team size, implementation process, and security requirements. I personally have encountered both but more often separated apps since many real life projects tend to be more complex.

### Separate apps

#### Pros:

- **More security** since you can enforce stricter security policies
- It enables you to **scale each component** independently based on your requirements
- Manage each component's **deployment process independently**
- **Easier to maintain and update** each component without affecting the other

#### Cons:

- Could add more **complexity to the application architecture**, making it harder to develop and troubleshoot
- It might **increase the operational cost**, especially if you need to provision additional resources for each component

### Single web app

#### Pros:

- It **simplifies the application architecture** and makes it easier to develop and troubleshoot
- Can **reduce the operational cost**, as you need to provision fewer resources and pay for fewer services
- **Simplifies the deployment process**, as you can deploy both components together

#### Cons:

- Can **limit the scalability** of the application, as you need to scale both components together
- Can **reduce the security** of the application, as a vulnerability in one component can affect the other